# How to resolve fixed table header border alignment issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to create a bordered table that has a fixed header, but the borders are not aligned. Any idea how to fix that issue?

```css
body{
  background-color: #bdc3c7;
}
.table-fixed{
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  tbody{
    height:200px;
    overflow-y:auto;
    width: 100%;
    }
  thead,tbody,tr,td,th{
    display:block;
  }
  tbody{
    td{
      float:left;
    }
  }
  thead {
    tr{
      th{
        float:left;
       background-color: #f39c12;
       border-color:#e67e22;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <table class="table table-bordered table-fixed">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="col-xs-3">First Name</th>
        <th class="col-xs-3">Last Name</th>
        <th class="col-xs-6">E-mail</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">John</td>
        <td class="col-xs-3">Doe</td>
        <td class="col-xs-6">johndoe@email.com</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">John</td>
        <td class="col-xs-3">Doe</td>
        <td class="col-xs-6">johndoe@email.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">John</td>
        <td class="col-xs-3">Doe</td>
        <td class="col-xs-6">johndoe@email.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">John</td>
        <td class="col-xs-3">Doe</td>
        <td class="col-xs-6">johndoe@email.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">John</td>
        <td class="col-xs-3">Doe</td>
        <td class="col-xs-6">johndoe@email.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">John</td>
        <td class="col-xs-3">Doe</td>
        <td class="col-xs-6">johndoe@email.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">John</td>
        <td class="col-xs-3">Doe</td>
        <td class="col-xs-6">johndoe@email.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">John</td>
        <td class="col-xs-3">Doe</td>
        <td class="col-xs-6">johndoe@email.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">John</td>
        <td class="col-xs-3">Doe</td>
        <td class="col-xs-6">johndoe@email.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">John</td>
        <td class="col-xs-3">Doe</td>
        <td class="col-xs-6">johndoe@email.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">John</td>
        <td class="col-xs-3">Doe</td>
        <td class="col-xs-6">johndoe@email.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">John</td>
        <td class="col-xs-3">Doe</td>
        <td class="col-xs-6">johndoe@email.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">John</td>
        <td class="col-xs-3">Doe</td>
        <td class="col-xs-6">johndoe@email.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">John</td>
        <td class="col-xs-3">Doe</td>
        <td class="col-xs-6">johndoe@email.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">John</td>
        <td class="col-xs-3">Doe</td>
        <td class="col-xs-6">johndoe@email.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">John</td>
        <td class="col-xs-3">Doe</td>
        <td class="col-xs-6">johndoe@email.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">John</td>
        <td class="col-xs-3">Doe</td>
        <td class="col-xs-6">johndoe@email.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">John</td>
        <td class="col-xs-3">Doe</td>
        <td class="col-xs-6">johndoe@email.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">John</td>
        <td class="col-xs-3">Doe</td>
        <td class="col-xs-6">johndoe@email.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="col-xs-3">John</td>
        <td class="col-xs-3">Doe</td>
        <td class="col-xs-6">johndoe@email.com</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/umertkxel/pen/jYbLdx

Comment: Please add your code in the question. A link can get broke.

Comment: Added code as a snipet.

Answer (score 0):

Give CSS styles to th,td.

For example,

```
td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is caused by the `overflow-y` in your `tbody` tag.
Why not try to set it `overflow-y:visible` instead of `overflow-y:auto`